# jquery DOM manipulation adding classes html

Tags: html, jquery

how would i add a class to the "col" of the just the "1 of 3"'s with out changing the bootstrap that it gives me

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        1 of 3
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        2 of 3 (wider)
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        3 of 3
      </div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col">
        1 of 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
        2 of 3 (wider)
        </div>
        <div class="col">
         3 of 3
        </div>

$("#col").addClass("hour");
```

});

Comment: I don't see any Jquery here. Please post the full code

Comment: just added it at the bottom

Comment: use `$(".row").addClass("hour");` id's shouldn't be declared twice

Comment: Orry is correct. Id's are for one specific item, classes can be used as many times as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML can't work with multiple same ids. ID must be unique.
If you want to add class to multiple elements, identify them by class instead.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="time" class="col">
        1 of 3
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        2 of 3 (wider)
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        3 of 3
      </div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="time" class="col">
        1 of 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
        2 of 3 (wider)
        </div>
        <div class="col">
         3 of 3
        </div>

$(".time").addClass("hour");
```

So you basically adding "hour" class to all elements with "time" class name

Comment: i just changed the questions because your answer helped but i dont want to add that class to the "col" of the " 3 of 3"'s

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the same ID for multiple elements. Behind the scenes, jQuery uses `document.getElementById()` whenever you use a `#xxx` selector. And that always returns just the first element with selected ID.

Use a class instead.